# What is the role of a director in a film?

Tags: directors

If everything is laid out in a script, then what is the use of director in a movie?

Comment: Avoid the chaos arising from tens of different interpretation of the script?

Comment: The director works from the script, to one extent or another, but usually feels free to change it on the fly according to filming conditions, the chemistry or abilities of the actors, an idea from the cinematographer, their own whim of what they think will work better..

Comment: What does a film director do? More or less the same things a *company's* director does. We might think they're overrated and overpaid, but take them out *and the entire thing falls apart*. They supervise the actual work done.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is way too broad to be answered in any reasonable way. What does the director do? He directs the movie.

Comment: Not to mention it's very easy to research an answer to this question.

Comment: Think of a Hitchcock movie without the vision of Hitchcock ... we'd never have all those great movies. The script only does so much: it's the director which makes a movie great ... well, the actors have a little something to do with that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The director of any enterprise is the one who holds a vision for how the finished result will look. In film, this means seeing that individual scenes will meld together into a cohesive film that has the visual and emotional impact that was intended. There are myriad details to tend to in any given scene - lighting, camera work, scenery, emotions of actors, dress, sound... and then there's continuity between scenes. The number of details and decisions required to make a 90 minute film must number in the thousands, and very little of that is laid out in the script.